# Cant update table in SQL c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Town which holds a relation between player and a players buildings. The table has the these Columns:
userid (int)
buildingid (int)
number (int)

I have successfully inserted a new building for a player and now i have trouble updating the specific row for a player.

I have this code:

```
if (!existPlayerBuilding(userid, buildingid))
            {
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                string query = "INSERT INTO Town VALUES(@userid, @buildingid, @number)";
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);

                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@userid", userid);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@buildingid", buildingid);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@number", number);

                try
                {
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception i)
                {
                    lblTestlabel.Text = "SQL FEILET";
                }
                lblTestlabel.Text = "Bygningen ble kjøpt!!!!";
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                string query = "UPDATE Town VALUES(@userid, @buildingid, @number) WHERE userid = @userid AND buildingid = @buildingid";
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(query, sqlcon);

                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@userid", userid);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@buildingid", buildingid);
                sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@number", number);

                try
                {
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlcon.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception i)
                {
                    lblTestlabel.Text = "SQL FEILET";
                }
                lblTestlabel.Text = "Bygningen ble kjøpt!!!!";
            }
```

The existPlayerBuilding method returns true if a player already has a building with the given id and false otherwise. When i run and test if i can update a number for a users building nothing happens.

Comment: It's often helpful to run problematic SQL commands in management studio to suss out syntax errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax for an Update in SQL would be

```
UPDATE Town
SET number = @number 
WHERE userid = @userid AND buildingid = @buildingid
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have know this... Anyway, now i know! :-P

Answer (score 6):

Your Update Query is wrong:

```
UPDATE Town
SET number = @number
WHERE userid = @userid AND buildingid = @buildingid
```

Comment: Darren, I voted for Jamiec's answer because I think there's some ambiguity that needs clearing up.  Your syntax is correct, but I'm not clear that the asker really wants to update BuildingID (or userID).

Comment: @peacedog - I understand.  From his query he states VALUES(userid, buildingid, number  - Therefore I am assuming he wishes to update these as his WHERE clause is correct. I will re edit to just include number.  Thanks